# Setting DataGridCell style trigger property not responding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I have a `DataGrid` with the Foreground initialized on white, like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="February"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Element[February].Value}" 
                    Width="*" 
                    Foreground="White" />
```

But when I try to set the foreground to black with a mouseover it's not working I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I could use some help, thank.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

**`EDIT: Full code`**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_TEST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="850
        ">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Margin="150,50,150,50" x:Name="GridBinding" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Month]}" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Oct." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[October].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nov." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[November].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="White"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dec." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[December].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="White"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Jan." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[January].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="White"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Feb." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[February].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mar." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[March].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apr." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[April].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="May" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[May].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="June" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[June].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="July" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[July].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aug." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[August].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sep." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[September].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Element[Depth].Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" 
                        BorderThickness="1">

                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      Margin="4,0,6,0" />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the StyleTrigger in the `ControlTemplate` of *`DataGridCell`* type. Instead of using white `Foreground` color, use `Transparent`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" 
                        BorderThickness="1">

                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      Margin="4,0,6,0" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>                
</Style>
```

This `Style` can be stored separately in resources, such as:

- in `Window.Resources`
- in `DataGrid.Style`
- in `App.xaml` - best place to store styles

Make sure that for the control not directly set the properties that must be set in the styles following, because local values ​​have a *higher* priority than the setter styles. Read more here:

[`MSDN: Dependency Property Value Precedence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)

That is setting the local value like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Oct." 
                    Foreground="Black" />
```

You "circumcise" a `Trigger` job and style setters.

Comment: I'm guetting an error of “Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.”

Comment: It's now working, but the background is black and the foreground is white I want the text black, but I'm not familiar with what you used

Comment: it doesn't do anything now when I hover the cell

Comment: I only need to make the text black and leave the white font there, bawsicly what I want is to make the text invisible until the user pass on it with his mouse

Comment: yes, I've searched alot and the best solution I've found would be by default the text is white and when the user put the mouse over the cell and then I can see the text

Comment: @Mokmeuh: For invisible text, better use `Transparent` color, it will be transparent for any background color. See my edit.

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not working as I mouse hover nothing happened

Comment: @Mokmeuh: Try remove `Foreground` value for `DataGridTextColumn`.

Comment: it's now working, why is working ( I removed the foreground of the datagridtextColumn)

Comment: Ok thank you, but the text only appear when I'm over the cell not when I'm in the cell, like it's not all the cell who triggers the text to appear it's only when I'm over the text, what I'm trying to do is when I'm anywhere in the cell the text appear

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46451/discussion-between-mokmeuh-and-anatoliy-nikolaev)